# update.message.reply_text('Hi!') Как это работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Наткнулся на эту строку и не могу понять как сделать класс так чтобы получилось слово1.слово2.функция('параметр'). Можно ли сделать цепочку больше? Что означают слово1 и слово2? Это функции какого-то класса? Приведите пожалуйста пример и объясните как это работает.

Comment: `слово2` — атрибут внутри объекта `слово1`, который содержит в себе какой-то объект; `функция` — атрибут внутри объекта `слово2`, который находится внутри объекта `слово1`, и так далее по аналогии до бесконечности

Comment: @andreymal Не факт. Возможно, это сделано через методы `__getattr__` и `__call__`, но как это работает я, к сожалению, ещё сам не знаю.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов если у автора вопросы такого уровня, лучше его getattr'ами пока не грузить)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас есть экземпляр класса слово1 в котором есть объект - слово2, который является экземпляром другого класса, у которого в свою очередь есть метод функция(). Внутри слова2 так-же может быть объект со своими методами или своими объектами и так далее.

Упрощенный пример

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, mess):
        self.message = mess

    def append_text_to_message(self, text):
        return self.message + text



class Updater():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var = var
        self.message = Message(self.var)


update = Updater('Message ')

x = update.message.append_text_to_message('text')


>>> x
'Message text'
```